# Inverted Index from multiple files

Tags: python, loops

I am a beginner in Python. I have to create an inverted index from multiple files. If a word appears in one file or more than one, it should display the tokenized word along with its respective file name like follow:

 cat [file1, file2]

  home [file2] 
money [file1 ,file2] 
 ans so on.
In short, I want to create a list of all words along with there respective file names.
'''

```
read_files = glob.glob('./*.txt')
array_values = []
for files in read_files:
   file_data = open(files).read()
   array_values.append(files)
#print(array_values)

   punc = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
   tok = punc.tokenize(file_data)
    
   ps = PorterStemmer()
   stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
   
   filtered_sentence = []
   for w in tok:
     s = ps.stem(w)
     if w not in stop_words:
       filtered_sentence.append(s)

       c=Counter(filtered_sentence)

 '''
```

I have done this far. I know there will be some loop but don't know how to implement that part. I have looked some of the questions asked here regarding this but I am unable to understand them. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I would use a dictionary where the keys would be the words and the values would be the list of files where it appears.

Comment: I would look at [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) and use that with `set.add()` on the files that contain the word. That would give you a dictionary with sets, that would eliminate duplicate entrys.